# Build xhtml dynamically from db data in ICEFaces

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml, icefaces

we are migrating our application from an existing custom web application framework to JSF/IceFaces.

we store window description in database: what kind of fields are on the window, what are their labels, etc.

Can I have my xhtml pieces generated dynamically in IceFaces?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good idea to handle these things using database. Its good to use xml/template-engines, instead.

**Suggestion:** Looking into [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) should help.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but unfortunately we are bound completely by the previously made design decisions. We have thousands of windows represented this way in the database and we have to show them up as they used to be shown before.

Answer (score 0):

metawidget might be a useful project in this case. 
It helps you to bind variable and render the ui.
Please check out the metawidget project www.metawidget.org

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and solved this by creating a custom JSF component
that extended class `javax.faces.component.UIInput`.  My custom
component reads the layout from the database and generates the 
HTML itself in the `encodeBegin()` and `encodeEnd()` methods.

The custom component is integrated as a custom tag into the XHTML page.

The following web pages describe creating custom JSF components:

http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364786/Building-Custom-JSF-UI-Components

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnavg.html